# How to hide specific files extensions (html & php) in URL?

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.html [L]
```

I am newbie and I have written this code and it is showing **"INTERNAL SERVER ERROR".Please help me with this!

Comment: Try this: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

Comment: Add RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f above my previous code.

Comment: Could you please check your Apache Error log for the reason of getting HTTP 500 Error?

Comment: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/

Comment: That means your Apache didn't loaded the Rewrite Engine for you. If you own the server or you can change the Apache settings, edit your php.ini, find mod_rewrite you will see a # at the front of the line. Remove it and restart Apache. (If you don't see any # in front of it that means you left the module uninstalled)

Comment: http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting/    I followed this link but error remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your current code by this one in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+?)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+?)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

Also, please make sure you enabled **mod_rewrite** in your Apache configuration